# How to clear values of all static variables at the end of an activity Android?

Tags: android, static-members

I have created an application that takes in user name and other details for a transaction and then fills them in a database. At times the application shows odd behavior by filling the SAME details in the database twice as two transactions. Even though the new values are read but not STORED in the static variables.

Therefore I needed help in flushing the values of all my static variables at the end of each activity to avoid overriding of the previous values in a fresh transaction.

EDIT :

```
  public class One
      {
  static String var;

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {    
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              var="blah";
         }
   }

          public class Two
            {
              static String variable = One.var;
               // This is where i am accessing the value of the variables from previous activities.

              //CODE
            }
```

Comment: please provide the relevant code.

Comment: why make it static if you want to flush the variables. you can create a check in inset logic of your database.

Comment: i think static variable are flushed on destroy of activity.. but as per you said its not happening.. right.??

Comment: @amrinder007, what code do you want to see? Its a simple case of static variables values' not getting flushed and holding on to the previous values rather than storing the new values.

Comment: @KKD, I have to make them static because I am sharing the values saved in one activity in the further activities. I am editing the question to explain that bit better.

Comment: @GarimaTiwari in that case why should youuse static variables use shared preferences or pass values to other activities using intents

Comment: @Raghunandan, using shared preferences does not suit my case, Intents sounds like a good idea but I'm trying to run till the end of this road before i switch to that. Isn't there a way around flushing the values of static variables at the end of an activity?

Comment: @GarimaTiwari static variables ares stored in permanent area in the heap. so using static variables is not a good idea. Check the link @ http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html under the topic Prefer Static Over Virtual

Comment: @Raghunandan, so i should just do away with the static variables you suggest. Also,helpful link. +1!

Comment: @GarimaTiwari yes don't use static variables

Answer (score 5):

May these help you..

Using Static Variables is like a nightmare in any activity as it stores memory through out the activity..

I think you can try some other memory store to overcome your problem of passing value from one activity to another..

In my opinion u can store values in SharedPreference or either you can pass value through intent to other activity where ever it is required..

Hope these will help you..

**EDIT:**

`Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);`

You can use more than one `putExtra()` method to put several values and can fetch then in Second Activity

`in.putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value);`

`StartActivity(in);`

**In Second Activity:**

`Intent in = getIntent();`

`ArrayList<String> Roleids = new ArrayList<String>;`

`RoleId = in.getStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value)`

Comment: If you have posted links in your answer I cant see them! Can you please edit ? Thanks ! :]

Comment: @Garima: have you ever used SharedPreference or Intent in programing..?? if no then i can provide you the code..

Comment: Lol. no thanks. I think im good on that count. Can you post some code on how to pass multiple string and integer values from one activity to another?

Comment: **MULTIPLE** values (strings and integers both).